# How can I apply an image to a specific border, using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply a background image, to a social media icon.  I undrstand how to apply an image as a background but where I am getting stuck, relates to the fact that there is a pseudo-element involved with transparency settings.  Here is my code:

```
#facebook-icon{
    background-color: #7d4826;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
    background-image: url("https://www.example.com/wood.png");
}

#facebook-icon::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-left: 18px solid #7d4826;
    border-right: 18px solid #7d4826;
    margin-left: -10px;
```

I need to insert the following code into my pseudo-element:

```
background-color: #7d4826;
background-image: url("https://www.example.com/wood.png");
```

I have tried various approaches but I seem to be overriding the transparency setting.

Has anyone any idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: It's not really clear what visual outcome you are trying to achieve from your code. Can you include a few screenshots, and perhaps a working example?

Comment: Could you post your HTML, and perhaps a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transparency is breaking because of the `background-color`

See the JSFiddle to understand. I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you stop using that property, you'll get your transparency back.

https://jsfiddle.net/ze71zuej/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried your suggestion, prior to posting here, but whilst it may work for colors, as soon as I apply a background, it overrides the transparency settings.